# Recovering software raid

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I have a 3-disk software raid 5. Two disk appear to have failed at the same time; their number of Events is the same, while other third disk's is higher. I have copied all three disks into new partitions so that I can experiment on them without hosing them further, and tried recreating the array with just the broken two (since they should be in the same state). But nothing I've tried gets me a usable superblock. Are there other things I can try to recover the data?

Here is the mdadm --examine for each drive:

```
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : f8d0c619:9f54ad08:bd0b98c0:101144a1
  Creation Time : Sun Jul 18 01:56:33 2010
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 488383936 (465.76 GiB 500.11 GB)
     Array Size : 976767872 (931.52 GiB 1000.21 GB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sat Sep 27 13:59:35 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 2
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : cbf4174b - correct
         Events : 5983

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1

   0     0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
   1     1       0        0        1      faulty removed
   2     2       0        0        2      faulty removed
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : f8d0c619:9f54ad08:bd0b98c0:101144a1
  Creation Time : Sun Jul 18 01:56:33 2010
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 488383936 (465.76 GiB 500.11 GB)
     Array Size : 976767872 (931.52 GiB 1000.21 GB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sat Sep 27 08:00:42 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : cbf3c2d6 - correct
         Events : 5940

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1

   0     0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
   1     1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   2     2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : f8d0c619:9f54ad08:bd0b98c0:101144a1
  Creation Time : Sun Jul 18 01:56:33 2010
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 488383936 (465.76 GiB 500.11 GB)
     Array Size : 976767872 (931.52 GiB 1000.21 GB)
   Raid Devices : 3
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sat Sep 27 08:00:42 2014
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0
       Checksum : cbf3c2e8 - correct
         Events : 5940

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 64K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1

   0     0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
   1     1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   2     2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mdadm --create --level 5 -n 3 --assume-clean -p ls -c 64 /dev/md0 missing /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
```

This creates the raid in the same way as it originally was, with a missing device.
Most importantly the number of devices, the layour, the chunk size and the order of the devices is the same. The `missing` device name together with --assume-clean) prevents any reinitializing, so you should be able to access the data again.

After creating the device again you can add a third disk to replace the missing one.

Comment: I'm a bit averse to trying this on the original disks yet, but I tried it on my copies with: `sudo mdadm --create --level 5 -n 3 --assume-clean -p ls -c 64 /dev/md1 missing /dev/sdb2 /dev/sdb3`. This creates without complaint, but e2fsck can't find the superblock.

Comment: The copies need to be on a device that is _exactly_ the same size as the original, as version 0.90 metadata is located at the end of the device. If you copied to a larger device, then the existing metadata can't be found. Using `losetup` with the `--sizelimit` option to create a loop device on your copies with the correct size could help. `mdadm --examine` on your copy should show the same information as you originally posted.

Comment: Yes, I had this problem the first time I created my copies. They are the correct size now, and `mdadm --examine` does show the same result.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the order of the component devices might not be correct, or the `--assume-clean` needs to be left off with a `missing` component. I've used this technique on a number of occasions (usually after someone pulled the wrong hotswap disk with the intent of replacing a failed drive, i.e. getting confused about which drive had failed), and never had problems.